# Recognizing a CWS code in a specific case

Tags: error-correction

A CWS code can be defined in terms of stabilizer codes/stabilizer states and graph states. See
[What is an example of a non-additive code that is not a CWS code?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32075/what-is-an-example-of-a-non-additive-code-that-is-not-a-cws-code)

Is the $ ((11,2,3)) $ nonadditive quantum error-correcting code given in [On the Structure of Additive Quantum Codes and the Existence of Nonadditive Codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9710031)
 a codeword stabilized code?

Certainly all the coefficients are $ \pm 1 $ up to a global scalar (in fact all the nonzero coefficients are $ +1 $) so that necessary condition is met.

Maybe there is some way of confirming this (or deriving a contradiction) by think about what graph that $ ((11,2,3)) $ code would have to correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a CWS code with parameters ((11,2,5)) with a graph specified in [1](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:894450/FULLTEXT01.pdf), p. 89.

Comment: Do you know if this $ ((11,2,5)) $ CWS code is equivalent to a stabilizer code?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. In general, CWS codes can have better parameters than stabilizer codes, e.g., there is a ((9,12,3)) and a ((10,24,3)) code outperforming the stabilizer codes  with the same number of qubits.